# Using two loops but only one loop runs through. Intro to computer science.(Java)

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a simple stock program. My first loop works but, it won't pass to my second one and I can't figure out why. I've tried breaks and if statements and I can't figure it out.

```
days = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of days in the stock period"); //Allows user to enter value
sharePoints = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the share points on the first day");   
int daynum = Integer.parseInt(days);
int share = Integer.parseInt(sharePoints);

int dayStart = 1;
double daynumMidPoint = (daynum/2);
System.out.println(share);
Math.round(daynumMidPoint);

for(int i = dayStart;i<daynumMidPoint;i++) {
    System.out.println(share=share+50);
}

for(int l = dayStart;l>=daynumMidPoint;l++){
    System.out.println(share=share-25);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly; I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: If the second loop didn't run, that means its condition is false. You need to debug to find out why that is.

Comment: Are you sure of the `l>=daynumMidPoint` part ?

Comment: the second loop is not logical while daystart is more than daynumMidPoint and then you are increasing daystart ?.Did you mean less than?

Comment: you are using same bound in both loopd bu with different operators, it can't work

Comment: your condition is false,l>=daynumMidPoint part

Comment: You probably need `for(int l = daynumMidPoint;l<daynum;l++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if the first loop works, the second one will not since the first loop will only start if `dayStart` is **under** `daynumMidPoint` and the second one will only start `dayStart` is **above or equal to** `daynumMidPoint`.

If the first one succeeds then the second one definitely will not.

Comment: Okay thank you. Now my new question becomes: How can I get my variable dayStart to hold value when entering the next loop? i.e it goes up to 11. How would I get it to start the next loop at that new variable

Comment: I assume you mean you want to carry the value of `i` over to the next loop (which would make sense because the second loop would actually start then). At the end of the first loop you can do `dayStart = i`. That will set the variable `dayStart` to the value of `i` which is the variable you created to initialize the loop. Through each iteration of the loop, `i` is incremented by 1 because you told it to when writing out the for loop (as seen by the end of the for loop).

Answer (score 0):

Your math is wrong and the condition for the second loop is not fulfilled

```
int dayStart = 1;
double daynumMidPoint = (daynum/2); // daynum = 10 ---> daynumMidPoint = 5
System.out.println(share);
Math.round(daynumMidPoint);

for(int i = dayStart;i<daynumMidPoint;i++) // i = 1, Condition: i < 5 = true
{
    System.out.println(share=share+50);
}
for(int l = dayStart;l>=daynumMidPoint;l++) // l = 1, Condition l >= 6 = false
{
    System.out.println(share=share-25);
}
```

So to fix this issue, you either need to adjust the condition for the second for loop.
Or you need to set l to a different start value.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that this

```
int dayStart = 1;
```

is set to one, this other loop wont work:

```
for(int l = dayStart;l>=daynumMidPoint;l++){
System.out.println(share=share-25);
```

since `l` is set to 1 and for the loop to run, you need `l` to be BIGGER or EQUAL than `daynumMidPoint`, and since this is set to `double daynumMidPoint = (daynum/2);` then it wont run since its bigger than `l`.

Seeing also that it seems you want Shares to increase if the current day is below the midpoint and decrease if the current day is above the midpoint, you can just put this(or something like this):

```
if(i<daynumMidPoint){
SOP(share=share+50);} 
else{
SOP(share=share-25);
}
```

inside this for-loop :

```
for(int i = dayStart;i<daynumMidPoint;i++) {

}
```